# Crash in dealloc in case of [viewcontroller release]. EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access

I am stuck. I don't know why its being crashing in the dealloc scope ? Guys please review the screen shot and let me know your ideas what should be the issue. I am getting "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" signal sticks in dealloc scope.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the related code of dealloc

Comment: You get a crash only if your view controller is already deallocated before you are releasing it. Check if your view controller object has memory at that point.

Comment: Posting some code would help!

Comment: I think Some of objects has been release first and then it's use.
have you write [super dealloc] in your dealloc method?
Please enable zobbie in your app and then run..I hope you get crash report more clearlly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of using released object,
first of all go to "Edit Scheme" and in Diagnostics for Objective-C "Enable Zombie Objects"

Then run your app in "Profile" mode which will open "Instruments"
here, select Zombies and press "Profile"

and run your app in simulator or device,
when your app being crashed it will show your perfect resign and location of crashing

its nothing but you have made minor mistake of release object.

Thanks & Regards,